# Knockout mapping of nested array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

This is my javascript that grabs the data and calls the mapping:

```
function loadData() {
    currentViewModel.isLoading(true);
    $.get('/api/myevents/' + eventId, null, function (data) {
        var details = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        currentViewModel.eventDetails(details);
    });
};

var viewModel = function () {
    var _self = this;
    this.eventDetails = ko.observable(null);
    this.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    this.addShow = function () {
        addShowDialog();
    };
};

var currentViewModel = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(currentViewModel);

loadData();
```

It seems to work okay until I added an array into the data that is returned. For some bizarre reason it doesn't get mapped by knockout.

I have attached screenshots of the objects either side of the mapping. I'm new to knockout in general, have I missed something fundamental here?

Thanks.

[image: Data returned from server]
[image: Data mapped by knockout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you judging failure by the `Shows: Object[0]` and `length: 0`? If you look at `_latestValue` you will see `Array[5]`.  An Array is mapped to an `ObservableArray`, which is a function.  You have to call the function - `Shows()`, in this case - to access the real array inside.

Here is a fiddle that shows that array mapping is working fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/VyH6y/

You can play with this sample to map to your exact scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that!